# Append column field name with date range operator dynamically in django?

Tags: python, django

This is the code I'm using :

```
where_con=''
#loop on model name
# getting all info for one model
    where_con = {}
    for k in model_k_j:
        type_val = type(model_k_j[k])
        if type_val== dict:
            print "dictonary type"
            """
            for model_field_dict in model_k_j[k]:
                start= model_k_j[k][model_field_dict]
                end= model_k_j[k][model_field_dict]
                where_con[k] =  medical_home_last_visit__range=[start,end ]
                break
            """
        else:
            col_name.append(k)
            where_con[k] =  model_k_j[k] 
    # covert data type
    # **where_con {unpack tuple}
    # where_con =str(where_con)
    # print where_con
    qs_new = model_obj.objects.filter(**where_con)
```

The field `medical_home_last_visit` is not static, it is coming dynamically. 
How do I append it ? I have tried something like:

```
colname_variable =  medical_home_last_visit 
where_con[k] =  colname_variable + __range=[start,end ]
```

but it is not working properly, and gives this error :

```
where_con[k] =  colname_variable + __range=[start,end ]
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This question is so badly formatted I cannot figure out what's being asked. Extra info added as comments don't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where_con` is dict and key name should be equal `colname_variable__range`:

```
#k = 'medical_home_last_visit__range'
where_con[k] = (start, end)
qs_new = model_obj.objects.filter(**where_con)
```

it is equal to:

```
model_obj.objects.filter(medical_home_last_visit__range=(start, end))
```

and any other filter args should be keys in `where_con`, for example:

```
#k = 'some_date__lte'
where_con[k] = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: column name is medical_home_last_visti and __range operator 
and column names are coming dynamically ...

where_con[k] = (start, end) 

in this not use __range operator 

please tell me how to use __range operator with this..

Comment: @user3016773 k in my code is not k in your code. Just make key name from column name and __range: where_con[column_name + '__range'] = (start, end)