# How to convert Mysql query for date range into Django query

Tags: python, mysql, django

`python` *Newbie* as well as `django` also,

**Question**:

I need to write one query for date range in Django

I know mysql query

```
SELECT * 
FROM productreport 
WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2014-10-12 00:00:00' and '2014-11-12 00:00:00' 
OR end_date BETWEEN '2014-10-12 00:00:00' and '2014-11-12 00:00:00';
```

I need to change above query dynamically using `filter(**kwargs)`

**Edited**:

```
def performance(request):
    daterangestart = str(request.POST['daterangepicker_start'])
    datereangeend = str(request.POST['daterangepicker_end'])
    kwargs['start_date__range'] =[str(daterangestart), str(datereangeend)]
    kwargs['end_date__range'] =[str(daterangestart), str(datereangeend)]
    reportDetails = productreport.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Please add your current view code and show where you are getting the date from :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146228/append-column-field-name-with-date-range-operator-dynamically-in-django

Comment: So what's wrong with the code you have posted? Looks like you are already using dynamic filters with `__range`.

Comment: can you share us your model class for productreport table.

Comment: @DanielRoseman how to add or condition in kwargs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q

date_filter = Q(start_date__range = [str(daterangestart), str(datereangeend)] )
date_filter |= Q(end_date__range = [str(daterangestart), str(datereangeend)] )
reportDetails = productreport.objects.filter(date_filter)
```